# How to find substring position in bytes in Python?

Tags: python, find, strpos

PHP:

```
$str = "абвгдежз";
$p = strpos($str, "г");
echo $str, "\n", $p;
```

result: 6

Python:

```
str = "абвгдежз"
p = str.find("г")
print(str); print(p)
```

result: 3

Comment: PHP `strpos()` doesn't count multibyte characters as one position, Python `find()` does. It's equivalent to PHP `mb_strpos()`

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `strpos()` is not multibyte-aware, so it's counting the bytes, not characters. To get the equivalent in Python you need to convert the strings to byte strings with `.encode()`

```
str = "абвгдежз"
search = "г"
p = str.encode().find(search.encode())
print(str)
print(p)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct: if "г" has 2 bytes, it can potentially take one byte from one character, and another byte from another character. E.g. assume that your byte encoding is `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, and you search for a character with encoding `[1, 2]`. I think this is correct: `len(str[:str.find("г")].encode())`

Comment: @Dmitry I think UTF encodings are designed so that can't happen.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I have no idea.

Comment: Also, if it can happen, it can also happen in `strpos()`, so it would get the same wrong answer.